# Pruning a AbstractTableModel without getValueAt() complications

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Is there a way to derive a pruned AbstractTableModel from a full AbstractTableModel without getValueAt() complications?

My full data (including userIds) is loaded into a JTable AbstractTableModel. However, for display purposes, I wish to derive a pruned AbstractTableModel of data associated with a particular userId.

I am beginning to think this is not possible because getValueAt intervenes and throws IndexOutOfBounds exceptions? These exceptions seem to occur becuase the pruned Data is not populated.

```
public class PrunedUserIdTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    TableModel fullModel;
    List columnIdentifiers;
    List tempDatum;
    List tempData; // holds tempDatums
    int rowCount; // reports pruned rowCount through getRowCount() method
    List prunedData; // intended to hold data of matched userId rows

    public PrunedUserIdTableModel(JTable fullTable, String userId) {
        fullModel = fullTable.getModel();
        columnIdentifiers = new ArrayList();
        tempDatum = new ArrayList();
        tempData = new ArrayList();
        rowCount = 0;

        List<Integer> userCount = new ArrayList<>(); 

        // Load columnIdentifiers from fullModel; omitted here

        // Go through fullModel searching for rows with matching userIds

        for (int i = 0; i < fullModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < fullModel.getColumnCount(); k++) {
                tempDatum.add(fullModel.getValueAt(i,k);
                if ((fullModel.getValueAt(i,k).equals(userId)) {
                    // Matching userId found; record relevant row
                    userCount.add(g);
                }
            }
            tempData.add(tempDatum);
            tempDatum.clear();  
        }

        // Now populate prunedData
        for (int j = 0; j < userCount.size(); j++) {
            prunedData.add(tempData.get(userCount.get(j)));
            rowCount=rowCount+1;
        }

        fireTableChanged(null);
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }  
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return fullModel.getColumnCount();
    }
    @Override
    public int getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // THROWS INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS EXCEPTION: Index 0; size 0
        List rowList = (List)prunedData.get(rowIndex);
        return rowList.get(columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `TableRowSorter` to filter your `JTable` rows to show only the ones you want. Then, be sure to call `convertRowIndexToView` and `convertRowIndexToModel` when you are referencing something by its index.